New flyway script to replace a "broken" script, old never be run?
We have this script name V1_0_15_1__anytext.sql and it was copied to a flyway system.
However it never succeeded as it had Insert Into ... Values (1,2, '${variable1}') and $variable was meant to be saved as-is without a flyway placeholder substitute.
Script failed on this line and rollbacked, my understanding Flyway had an error as it did not have a value for ${variable1} substitute, default flyway placeholder prefix=${  | suffix=} conflict.
So this V1_0_15_1 was never succeeded, how do we provide a new flyway script without ${...} substring syntax. we changed our application level substitute syntax.

script may still be overriden V1_0_15_1__anytext.sql the original filename?
OR leave this "broken" script as is and provide a new V1_0_15_2__anytext.sql filename?
OR leave this "broken" script as is and provide a new V1_0_15_1_1__anytext.sql filename?


If the script hasn't been applied (ie it rolled back) why not just edit it and run it again?

@DavidAtkinson so my 1st option may work, (backround: we "just" provide scripts and flyway sysop runs the files as usual without manual edits).

Which database type is this?

@DavidAtkinson This is MySQL run on Azure environment., same script also had few ALTER TABLE ADD column ... lines.

If a script fails, unless it has rolled back via a transaction, it will leave Flyway in a failed status. You can check by running "flyway info" against the target. If this has happened you need to run "flyway repair" to tell the target that it's in a good state to run migrations again.

As far as I'm aware MySQL doesn't have transactions, so this most likely will result in needed a "flyway repair" to be run before trying to run "flyway migrate" again.

This script had ALTER TABLE ... lines, after that following few INSERTs, a very last line was "INSERT INTO ... "${variable1}" substring which most likely gave a flyway error.
Target system most likely has alter table changes applied (implicit mysql commit) but after that INSERTs were tx rollbacked.
Only open question is what filename be used if I want to replace an existing script (may still the original name or must use 3rd option)
I am not sure as do not have a flyway control or even see the target db system.

Customer made an adhoc edit on a broken script, fixed a db manually and rerun a migration. We also provided a next sequence of _16_1__fix.sql script to rerun the same InsertUpdate data modifications just in case.
